# open magnificPopup Ajax popUp with jQuery

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

I'm using an AJAX popup with [magnificPopUp](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/). I would like to open this popup within a jQuery click event but I don't now how to to that.

```
$('.popup').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('rel');
    url = '/test-ajax.php?id=' + id;
    alert("url" + url); //this shows the URL where the popUp should load
})
```

The "normal" magnific PopUp Class looks so:

```
$('.simple-ajax-popup-align-top').magnificPopup({
    type: 'ajax',
    alignTop: true,
    overflowY: 'scroll' 
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming your ajax call produces HTML string, you can try something like this:

```
$('.popup').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('rel');
    url = '/test-ajax.php?id=' + id;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        success: function(result) {
            $('.simple-ajax-popup-align-top').magnificPopup({
                alignTop: true,
                overflowY: 'scroll',
                items: {
                    src: result,
                    type: 'inline'
                }
            }).magnificPopup('open');
        },
    });
});
```

What the code does essentially is fire the ajax call (documented [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)). On ajax success callback, it triggers the magnificpopup, insert the result (which is the HTML string gotten from the ajax call) into the magnificpopup via "items" property (documented [here](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#content-types) and [here](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#api) - see the section right above "Public properties")

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long, but it is expected.